# Add onClickListener to not exist textView in android

Tags: android, jquery, listview, onclicklistener

I am web developer before I heading to android development. I can achieve this with the code below in jquery

```
$(document).on("click",".textView",function(){});
```

So in android I have a list view that will dynamically load new content from the server.
Inside the listView have a textView and some content. So how can I add onClickListener just to every textView inside the listView?? Android unable to share the same id this make me more hard to solve it.

Any Help will be highly apperciate :)

Comment: Please follow some example tutorials about using ListView.

Comment: You will need to make your own adapter. Check out Section 3.3 in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html. In the "getView" method, you can then add onclick listeners to the textview.

Comment: @Squonk I just follow the listView will not make the thing what I want. I want something like twitter/facebook home feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this listview tutorial links

http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview
and
 http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
and
 http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90